# plane at infinity in projective space from intrinsic parameters

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision, 3d

Suppose cameras are calibrated therefore Metric projection matrices M_i(3x4) are there for view i from multiple views. As well, K_i(3x3) the camera matrix of each view is available. Can we calculate the location of plane at infinity in projective space?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, the plane at infinity is always the plane where w = 0.  If you are applying affine transformations, it remains fixed.  It only shifts if you use a homography.

Comment: That I know, but I need it's location in projective space. That means W is no longer 0!

Comment: No, it is still the same plane in projective space.  An affine transformation fixes the projective plane (by definition).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is theoretically  possible. The plane at infinity always remains fixed in terms of the actual projective 3D world. However, it is imaged differently by a moving camera upon each view and in these cases we say that the plane at infinity is not at its canonical position. Instead of thinking that the camera moved, it is more convenient to think that the entire 3D projective space has moved! Thus, we invent a 3D homography to "blame" for this change. Mathematically, the 3D homography tags along the left side of the projection matrix:
                              x = (P*H)*X
So, to answer the question: Although tricky, yes you may recover it, given that you have sufficiently enough reconstructed views of the scene. This is a process called auto calibration and it essentially involves one equation (that comes in many flavors) but unfortunately, gives non-linear equations. I suggest you look at the following:

http://nguyendangbinh.org/Proceedings/CVPR/1999/DATA/03_34.PDF

I believe it contains the most up-to-date method to iteratively compute the plane at infinity.